# Making webpages accessible only by the navigation menu on website

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way that I can make sure that all the pages of my website are accessible only by the navigation menu available at the website and no one can access that page using the address bar.

For example, let's say I have my website hosted at `http://www.foobar.com` and there are pages `http://www.foobar.com/home`, `http://www.foobar.com/contact` etc. Is there any way that I can  restrict these pages to not be accessed by entering these addresses and only by the navigation I have provided on my website?

Comment: Not likely, but I would also love to hear any ideas :)

Comment: You'd be able to make it difficult, but I don't think you'll be able to prevent it entirely. You could do something like appending some sort of string to the link from the nav bar and block access if that parameter is not present. This could be bypassed quite easily by inspecting the markup of the page though...

Comment: What abount generating some kind of random token within the click-event of the navigation item (client-side), then tell the server what token to expect (via Ajax), then redirect the user with the token (still client-side). Then, on the server-side, check if the correct token was provided. Of course, this only works as long JavaScript is enabled on the client-side.

Comment: @azeós out of curiosity ;)

Comment: @KamranAhmed: fair enough =]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well… you could encode all the data to be in a non-human readable form (such as ROT 13), protect access to it with an anti-CSRF-style nonce, and load it using XMLHttpRequest so you can decode it with JavaScript before adding it to the page…

… but the whole idea is contrary to the idea of the web and is really user hostile.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use the following method:

1. On client-side attach `click` handler to each nav menu link where
   some token value storing in cookie by Javascript.
2. On server-side check visitor's cookies on presence of appropriate
   token as well as check its value.

The code may look like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="..." class="nav-menu">...</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.nav-menu').click(function(){
        // setCookie() is function that set Javascript cookie
        setCookie('mytoken', 'mytoken_value');
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['mytoken']) && $_COOKIE['mytoken'] == 'mytoken_value') {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a form with every navigation menu option with different hidden input values and check the value while on your other page like contact. If the post value is not there, you can  redirect the page back to old page.
But this idea is not user friendly as users are used to navigate directly to other pages mostly due to browser site suggestion from history and also due to there memory to remember exact site because they don't want to go to homepage first.